# Segmentation fault core dumped error in c

Tags: c

Each time I run this c code I get a segmentation fault (core dumped)...so the array gets printed and everything and in the end of the printing it fives me this segmentation fault...I tried putting a break after the if, the error code does not appear but it only now reads one line and doesn't read multiple

```
int main(int argc, char* arg[]){
    if (argc != 2){ 
        puts("Error: Usage is caesarcipher <offset>");
        exit(1);
    }
    int i = 0;
    int input;
    char array[100];
    while ((input = getchar())!= '\0'){
        if (input == '\n'){
            array[i] = '\0'; 
            printf("%s\n", array);
            i = 0;
        }else{  
            array[i] = input;
            i += 1;}}
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have nothing to prevent you from writing past the end of the array[100] array.  Certainly, if you input more than 100 characters a segmentation fault is not only possible but likely.  For starters, add checks to see if I is >99 and abort.  However, if the lines you are reading are short, I don't know why you are getting the fault.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the documentation for `getchar()`, particularly the return value which indicates an error.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar.  "Return value:
The obtained character on success or **EOF** on failure."  `EOF` is never the same as `'\0'`.

Comment: yes I understood...the code worked...thank you very much